# How can I paginate image attachments in a post?

Tags: pagination, get-children

I have a post with attached images and I was able to display the images but I'm can't seem to find a way to paginate the results. I am using get_children but now I'm wondering if my method of displaying the images is the right way to do it or not. What other methods can I use? Thanks!

Comment: Use `paginate_links()`. Won't be easy, but it's doable and we got example on the site by @ChipBennet.

Comment: See here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/154945/9884

Answer (score -1):

I doubt you could paginate within a post display. It would be more effective to display all the image attachments at the page load, and have a script do the pagination.

You can find a lot of them on such sites:
http://www.themeflash.com/30-powerful-jquery-slideshow-sliders-plugins-and-tutorials/

You need to be able to edit your template files, specifically the header and post parts.

If you don't want to muddle in your template, and don't need to have the slider right on the side, you could easily install a lightbox wordpress extension that would generate an output with a pop-up window in which you can switch between images.